# how to use Websphere datasource in Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I need to use websphere data source in my spring batch,

I tried to use

```
<bean id="wasdataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/testdb" />
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

> SQL state [null]; error code [0]; DSRA9110E: ResultSet is closed.; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ObjectClosedException: DSRA9110E: ResultSet is closed.

Also

```
<bean id="wasdataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.WebSphereDataSourceAdapter">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
             <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/testdb"/>
             </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>
```

> Specified 'targetDataSource' is not a WebSphere WSDataSource: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@4f68bc63

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but my answer is not directly related to WebSphere, but we are successfully using datasources under Jboss. So since you got no specific answers, I thought I could help with my Jboss experience...

We define the datasource as follow:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="sampleDS" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/sampleDS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" lookup-on-startup="false" cache="true" />
```

And it works nicely...

In order to use the `jee` tag, you must include `xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"` into `<beans>` declaration and  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd` into `xsi:schemaLocation`.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Bob